# Requesting to oracle with nodejs using promises

Tags: node.js, oracle, typescript, npm, promise

I'm trying to execute a block function in oracle in nodejs but I get no response and this after 10sec :

```
UnhandledPromiseRejectionWarning: Unhandled promise rejection (rejection id: 1): Error: Mauvaise requête: Error: ORA-12170: TNS:Connect timeout occurred
```

In the meantime the code continued to execute. Here is my workflow :

```
const jwtTokenResponse: any = await authService.userLogin(req.body);
```

then in userLogin

```
const result = await oracleHelper.executeBlockFunction(block, bindVars);
```

and finally the function :

```
  async executeBlockFunction(block: any, bindVars: any): Promise<any> {

    logger.info(`--> ` + 'executeBlockFunction : ' + config.oracle.user + ' / ');
    logger.info(`--> ` + 'executeBlockFunction : ' + config.oracle.password + ' / ');
    logger.info(`--> ` + 'executeBlockFunction : ' + config.oracle.connectString + ' / ');
    oracledb.getConnection(
      {
        user: config.oracle.user,
        password: config.oracle.password,
        connectString: config.oracle.connectString,
      }).then(function (connection) {
      logger.info(`--> connected`);
      return connection.execute(
        block,
        bindVars,
      ).then(function (result) {
        logger.info(`--> ` + result.rows);
        return connection.close();
      }).catch(function (error) {
        logger.info(`--> ` + error.message);
        return connection.close();
      });
    }).catch(function (error) {
      throw new OracleError(
        new Error(error),
      );
    });
  }
```

As you can see I checked the entries, everything is fine before `oracledb.getConnection` after that I don't understand what is happenning

Can someone Help me with this ?

EDIT :

For information `executeBlockFunction` content was taken from oracleDb npm documentation :

> [Oracle documentation link](https://github.com/oracle/node-oracledb/blob/master/doc/api.md#promiseoverview)

Comment: can you share the content of config.oracle.connectString

Comment: I see this is already answered, but this post may be helpful too: https://jsao.io/2017/07/how-to-get-use-and-close-a-db-connection-using-async-functions/

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You should add `await` keyword in `executeBlockFunction` function, or remove `async` keyword and return result:

Solution 1:

```
async executeBlockFunction(block: any, bindVars: any): Promise<any> {
    await oracledb.getConnection(...)
```

Solution 2:

```
executeBlockFunction(block: any, bindVars: any): Promise<any> {
    return oracledb.getConnection(...)
```

Or, so as you already using `async/await` you can refactor/simplify your code:

```
async executeBlockFunction(block: any, bindVars: any): Promise<any> {
  try {
    let connection = await oracledb.getConnection({
      user: config.oracle.user,
      password: config.oracle.password,
      connectString: config.oracle.connectString,
    });
    logger.info(`--> connected`);

    let result = await connection.execute(block, bindVars);
    logger.info(`--> ` + result.rows);

    return result;
  } catch (err) {
    logger.info(`--> ` + error.message);
    throw new OracleError(err));
  } finally {
    return connection.close();
  }
}
```

Comment: Your response is actually really good, I'm new using nodejs and promises and this kind of simplification makes sens. I'll it thanks.